# "To be survived by someone of some years"

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, verbs, phrases

I saw the definition of the verb survive in a dictionanry with this example: Santos is survived by his wife of 49 years.
I understand that his wife is still alive when Santos passed away, but what does the phrase "of 49 years" mean? Does it mean she is 49 years old when he died?

Answer (score 3):

"wife of 49 years" refers to the amount of time *she was his wife*, not the amount of time *she was alive*: they had been married for 49 years when he died. Presumably she is much older than 49.